# Nginx loadbalancing, Is there a way to do this?

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, load-balance

I want to use a test server for administrators.

Is there a way to assign an access from the client of ip(`123.0.0.1`) to the server of ip(`123.0.0.2`)?

```
upstream target-server {  
  server [123.0.0.3] ;
  server [123.0.0.2] ;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use if statement in location to map traffic to your service.

```
upstream target-server {
server 123.0.0.3 ; 
server 123.0.0.2 ; }
server{
***
  location / {
    if ($remote_addr = 123.0.0.1) {
          proxy_pass http://123.0.0.2 ;
    }
    proxy_pass http://target-server ;
  }
}
```

Comment: I want to use like this . 123.0.0.*(all) how can i do ??

Comment: I believe something like ($remote_addr ~ 123.0.0 ) within if condition may work. 
There are multiple conditions in nginx. For example this https://gist.github.com/jrom/1760790